# How to add dropdown menu connected to database in flask-admin flask-sqlalchemy Python?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-admin

[my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrDXQ.png)
I have drop down menu that i created with flask-admin View class

```
class ViewWards(MyAdminIndexView):
create_template = "admin/mapcreate.html"
    edit_template = "admin/map.html"
    column_labels = {
        'id':'ID',
        'first_name' :'Имя',
        'last_name' : 'Фамилия',
        'about':'О подопечном',
        'geo_point_x':'Широта',
        'geo_point_y':'Долгота',
        'fixed_summa': 'Фиксированная ли сумма',
        'summa':'Сумма',
        'type' : 'Тип подопечного'
    }
    data = json.loads(get_wards_types()[0])
    new_list = []
    for e in data:
        new_list.append((e["type"],e["type"]))
    AVALIABLE_WARDS_TYPES = new_list
    AVALIABLE_WARDS_TYPES = [
        (1, 2),
        (2, 2),
    ]
    print(AVALIABLE_WARDS_TYPES[0])
    form_choices = {
        'type':AVALIABLE_WARDS_TYPES
    }
```

How can i connect my AVALIABLE_WARDS_TYPES to form_choices for example, if database will be updated with new types, this types should be on my webpage. Or there is another way to create dropdown menu connected to DB?
Im using flask-admin, flask-sqlalchemy.

Here is declaring of wards model

```
class wards(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__ = "wards"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    about = db.Column(db.Text(300))
    geo_point_x = db.Column(db.Float)
    geo_point_y = db.Column(db.Float)
    fixed_summa = db.Column(db.Boolean(1))
    summa = db.Column(db.Integer)
    type = db.Column(db.String(30))
    pass
```

Tried to connect form choices to DB but its only working one time after starting programm.